# Custom data type in umbraco 7

Tags: types, umbraco

can someone help me? I have to create a custom datatype for umbraco 7, that  contains standart data type relateve links with images. I tried to write this by myself, but i cant understand how it create with AngularJS, because i had never used it before.

Comment: There are lots of great resources for this so i won't repeat here - but please check out these most informative posts from Warren Buckley  + Tim Geyssens:
http://creativewebspecialist.co.uk/2013/08/23/how-i-built-my-first-property-editor-for-umbraco-belle/

http://www.nibble.be/?p=285

Answer (score 2):

The tutorials for extending the Umbraco 7 back-office are here:

http://umbraco.github.io/Belle/#/tutorials/CreatingAPropertyEditor